# Gradle : How to call implicit task provided by application plugin from other task

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to execute run task provide by 'application' plugin after completion of 'copySrcToTempDir' task.

i tried

1)run.dependsOn copySrcToTempDir  -> BuildFail

2)run.mustRunAfter copySrcToTempDir  ->But won't execute run task.

```
 apply plugin:'application'

        repositories {
           flatDir {
               dirs 'lib'
           }
        }
        dependencies {
           compile name: 'zip4j_1.3.2'
        }
        mainClassName = "com.md.zippwd.ZipWithPassword"

        task copySrcToTempDir(type: Copy){
        from "D:\\DemoProject"
        into "D:\\Temp"
      }
    }
    // run.dependsOn copySrcToTempDir      
    // run.mustRunAfter copySrcToTempDir   

provided gradle command accordingly

gradle copySrcToTempDir  

gradle run

please suggest me i'm not finding any solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin:'application'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']

    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'lib'
       }
    }
    dependencies {
       compile name: 'zip4j_1.3.2'
    }
    mainClassName = "com.md.zippwd.ZipWithPassword"

    task copySrcToTempDir(type: Copy){
    from "D:\\DemoProject"
    into "D:\\Temp"
  }
}

task finaltask(dependsOn: ['copyArsWebApp', 'run'])
```

Description

```
We need to add sourceSet if folder is not like  src->java->main

and to use run task, make it is independent because it already depending upon application plugin's task like compile , classes ....
```

Thanks alot Ajay Deshwal.

Answer (score 0):

run.dependsOn copySrcToTempDir is working for me. I am using gradle 2.5. Which gradle task are you executing? run?

Try using:

```
tasks.run.dependsOn("copySrcToTempDir")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply
but i am getting error


:copyArsWebApp
:run
Error: Could not find or load main class com.md.zippwd.ZipWithPassword
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
------------------------

It is skipping task prior to run task

:compileJava 
:processResources 
:classes

Comment: Please share your gradle file.

Comment: I have updated the question and added exact code of the file 

>I think if we explicitly make depend our own task to run task

>The run task is avoiding It's Implicit dependent task